# Reducing space between LineLegend row and top of frame?

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

I am trying to reduce the space between my plot's `FrameLabel`, which is in the form of a `LineLegend`, and the top of the plot's frame. Is there an easy way to do this? A simplified version of my code is:

```
Plot1 = Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t], {t, 0, 100}, 
  ImageSize -> Automatic -> Medium, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
  PlotRange -> {0, 1}, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {None, None, 
    LineLegend[{Gray, Red, Black}, {"test1", "test2", "test3"}, 
     LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}, 
     LegendMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSquare]", 
        20}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 20}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}}]}]
```

Comment: Add `LegendMargins -> 0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p1 = Plot[1000*Exp[-0.03*t]
  , {t, 0, 100}
  , ImageSize -> Automatic -> Medium
  , PlotStyle -> {Black}
  , PlotRange -> {0, 1000}
  , Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}}
  , FrameLabel -> {{None, None}, {None, None}}
  , ImagePadding -> {{40, 10}, {30, 10}}
  ];

g1 = Graphics[
  Inset[
   LineLegend[{Gray, Red, Black}
    , {"test1", "test2", "test3"}
    , LegendLayout -> {"Row", 1}
    , LegendMarkers -> {{"\[FilledSquare]", 
       20}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]", 20}, {"\[FilledCircle]", 20}}
    , LegendMargins -> 0
    ]
   , {50, 1000}
   ]
  , PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {995, 1005}}
  ];

Grid[{{g1}, {p1}}, Spacings -> {0, -0.4}]
```

[image]